# Add a textView on my class gameView

Tags: android, android-canvas, game-engine

I am currently developing a game for android .I want add a textview on my class gameView .
this my code:

Class main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<app.com.GameView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/game_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<TextView 
        android:id = "@+id/score_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is class Activity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private app.com.GameView gameView ;
private TextView scoreText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gameView = (app.com.GameView)findViewById(R.id.game_view);
    scoreText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score_text);
    gameView.setScoreText(scoreText);
}
```

This is calss GameView :

```
private int score = 0;

 private TextView scoreText;

public void setscoreText(TextView tv){

this.scoreText = tv;
}
```

But when I use scoreText.setText(""+score), It was a error exception "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."? Please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't used'? Any exception observed when trying to call setText?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : scoreText.setText(String.valueOf(score));

Edit :

I think that you must use Handler class for send message to interact with UI.
You have a great example in sample of Android SDK named LunarLander, a game too.

I hope that help you.

Comment: I try do it.But it don't successful

Answer (score 1):

You cant set the text using an integer.

It first needs to be converted to a string. The easiest way is:

```
scoreText.setText(score + "");
```

or

```
scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(score));
```